# Location and weather based image search API for weather app

Tags: javascript, api, weather

I am making a basic web-based weather app, which detects the current weather conditions in the user's location. My current code so far does work, but is missing an important feature - I want the background of the web page to change according to the user's location and weather conditions. For instance - if a user is in New York and the weather is sunny, I would like to display any New York based popular image(ex: Times Square) along with sunny skies as the `body` background. I've searched several APIs but haven't found any that meets my needs.

In my current code, I'm using [IPInfo.io](http://ipinfo.io/) to get the user's location and [OpenWeatherMap](http://openweathermap.org/) to get the weather conditions.

This [pen](http://codepen.io/Nyxx/full/VepOqj/) has my code (NOTE - code for units hasn't been added yet), and here's the JS bit -

```
var lat = 0.0,
    lon = 0.0;

var testURL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0';
var myURL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon + '&appid="ae0acb60e8db4952e081c2fb470a1b23"';

var city = '',
    state = '',
    country = '',
    postal = 0;


//if (navigator.geolocation) {
//    /* geolocation is available */
//    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
//        lat = position.coords.latitude;
//        lon = position.coords.longitude;
//        console.log("Latitude = " + lat);
//        console.log("Longitude = " + lon);
//
//        display(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
//    });
//
//} else {
//    /* geolocation IS NOT available */
//    $("#jumbotron").html("geolocation not available");
//
//}

//get co-ordinates using ipinfo.io
$.getJSON('http://ipinfo.io', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    var loc = data.loc;
    lat = loc.split(",")[0];
    lon = loc.split(",")[1];
    display(lat, lon);
    city = data.city;
    state = data.region;
    country = data.country;
    postal = parseInt(data.postal, 10);

})


function display(x, y) {
    $("#pos1").html("<b>" + x + "</b>");
    $("#pos2").html("<b>" + y + "</b>");
}

//function to calculate wind direction from degrees
function degToCompass(num) {
    //num = parseInt(num, 10);
    console.log("Inside degtocompass = " + num);

    var val = Math.floor((num / 22.5) + 0.5);
    var arr = ["N", "NNE", "NE", "ENE", "E", "ESE", "SE", "SSE", "S", "SSW", "SW", "WSW", "W", "WNW", "NW", "NNW"];
    return arr[(val % 16)];
}

//function to return current temperature
function convertTemp(currTemp) {

    //get celsius from kelvin
    return Math.round(currTemp - 273.15);
}

$("button").click(function () {
    console.log("In Latitude = " + lat);
    console.log("In Longitude = " + lon);

    //prepare api call
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon + '&appid=ae0acb60e8db4952e081c2fb470a1b23',
        //url: testURL,
        type: 'GET', // The HTTP Method, can be GET POST PUT DELETE etc
        data: {}, // Additional parameters here
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            console.log(data);

            //---------get the clipart---------------
            var picLink = 'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/';
            var picName = data.weather[0].icon;
            picLink += picName + ".png";

            $("#picture").empty().append('<img src="' + picLink + '">');


            //----------get the temperature-----------
            var curTemp = convertTemp(data.main.temp);
            console.log("Current temp = " + curTemp);
            //$("#temp").empty().append("<b>" + curTemp + "</b>");
            $("#picture").append("<b>" + curTemp + "</b>");



            //----------get the place----------------------
            var area = city + ", " + state + ", " + country;
            $("#area").empty().append("<b>" + area + "</b>");


            //----------get weather conditions------------
            $("#conditions").empty().append("<b>" + data.weather[0].description + "</b>");

            //----------get wind speed------------
            //get wind direction
            var windSpeed = degToCompass(data.wind.deg);
            //add wind speed
            windSpeed += ' ' + data.wind.speed;
            //display wind speed
            $("#wind-speed").empty().append("<b>" + windSpeed + "</b>");





        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err);
        },
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            //xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization", "32ROUuaq9wmshfk8uIxfd5dMc6H7p1lqdZSjsnXkB5bQtBteLK"); // Enter here your Mashape key
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Just to clarify what you are asking - You are looking for an API to a service that provides image based on location and weather condition?  Or do you want to work out how to write the code that will do that without an API?

Comment: I was initially hoping for the first way. But if there's a way to write the code that would do this thing without using a web service, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 0):

Well... First of all there is no need to use WebServices, but you can't do it without any API. As I can see you use openweathermap API . As far as I know this API returns both longitude and latitude, so you can use these values as input to another request to a photo API (like flickr) to get the image you want. Moreover openweathermap API returns city name which can make your photo request even more accurate.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17513029)

Comment: This provides an answer to the question ! Basically an initial answer as I'm not eligible to provide comments ! Maybe sometimes the policy of over 50 reputation to comment should be revised !